# cannot implements with the onBindViewHolder in my class extends RecyclerView.Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I just join this forum within a week and I have encountered a problem with RecyclerView.Adapter in Android.

By following the sample codes and the documentation, I tried to build a custom adapter class by myself and it stuck at one of the methods inherited from its superclass, RecyclerView.Adapter. Although I write an inner class inherited the viewholder just like the sample code, it still have errors when it comes to the *onBindViewHolder()*

here is my code of the inner class:

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
   private final TextView tvTitle,tvDate,tvTime;
   public ViewHolder(View v){
        super(v);

        Log.d(TAG,"building view holder");

        tvTitle=v.findViewById(R.id.item_tvTitle);
        tvDate=v.findViewById(R.id.item_tvDate);
        tvTime=v.findViewById(R.id.item_tvTime);

        //set onclick listener to start another activity
        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
       });
   }

   public TextView getTvTitle(){return tvTitle;}
   public TextView getTvDate(){return tvDate;}
   public TextView getTvTime(){return tvTime;}
}
```

here is my code of the adapter:

```
public class EventAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    private static final String TAG="EventAdapter";
    private Event[] dataset;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private final TextView tvTitle,tvDate,tvTime;
        public ViewHolder(View v){
            super(v);

            Log.d(TAG,"building view holder");

            tvTitle=v.findViewById(R.id.item_tvTitle);
            tvDate=v.findViewById(R.id.item_tvDate);
            tvTime=v.findViewById(R.id.item_tvTime);

            //set onclick listener to start another activity
            v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });
        }

        public TextView getTvTitle(){return tvTitle;}
        public TextView getTvDate(){return tvDate;}
        public TextView getTvTime(){return tvTime;}
    }

    public EventAdapter(List<Event> dataset){
        Log.d(TAG,"Constructor, converting list to array");
        this.dataset=dataset.toArray(new Event[dataset.size()]);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup container,int viewType){
        Log.d(TAG,"onCreateViewHolder");
        View v= LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_event,container,false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position){
        Log.d(TAG,"onBindViewHolder");

        viewHolder.getTvTitle().setText("Title: "+dataset[position].getTitle());
        viewHolder.getTvDate().setText("Date: "+dataset[position].getDate());
        viewHolder.getTvTime().setText("Time: "+dataset[position].getTime());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){return dataset.length;}
}
```

And here are the errors it shows:

```
1. class 'EventAdapter'(which is my class inherited from the adapter) must either declared as abstract or implements abstract method onBindViewHolder(VH,int) in 'Adapter'
2. method(means the onBindViewHolder) does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

Thanks for solving my problem

Comment: show code from RecyclerView Adapter, please.

Comment: @YriiBorodkin,edited. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to successfully compile, change

```
public class EventAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EventAdapter.ViewHolder>
```

and

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(EventAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class EventAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EventAdapter.ViewHolder> {

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}
```

}